# Proper formatting for Javascript collection

Tags: javascript, jshint

What's the "proper" way to format a Javascript collection?

I'm trying to run [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) on my Javascript files, to clean up and correct any major formatting problems, but I'm getting a ton of nonsense errors like:

```
Expected a string and instead saw key.
```

because I define many collections like:

```
var data = {key: "value"};
```

Is this not legal or accepted Javascript?

Obviously, I can fix it by changing it to:

```
var data = {"key": "value"};
```

but I'd rather not give myself a ton of extra work just to make a pointless aesthetic change. Obviously, the first form could possibly interpret `key` as a variable that doesn't contain the text "key", but I've never had an issue. All the Javascript examples I've ever seen tend to treat the two representations as interchangeable.

Comment: Both ways are syntactically valid. Don't let linting become more trouble than it's worth... although, this seems to be an unpopular opinion.

Answer (score 0):

According [MDN Creating new objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects) description there is nothing wrong with either way of defining the object. In fact there are 3 different ways to define the name of the object: either a name, a number, or a string literal. Please see an example of the usage ...

```
var car = { manyCars: {a: "Saab", "b": "Jeep"}, 7: "Mazda" };
console.log(car.manyCars.b); // Jeep
console.log(car[7]); // Mazda
```